# VBA How to declare an array with elements with different datatype

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array that I have created to store error records and it has the following elements:
Serial No,File name, error type, error cell, error cell value

As of now I have declared my array like this and then I populate the values later on.

```
Dim errorArray() As String
```

But ideally, I want Serial Number to be a proper integer, but it is getting converted into string. I don't know how to declare this correctly so that I can have Long datatype for the first element and string for the next 3 and variant for the last one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to create an array of type Variant. An array of type Variant can store any data type in any of its elements.

```
Dim astrItems(0 To 9)    As String
Dim varItems             As Variant

varItems = astrItems
```

Comment: So obvious, but I missed it. In fact, I was thinking that I declared an array of type Variant, so I was a bit confused when I saw your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Create a private type in your code, like this:

```
Private Type ErrRecord
    SerialNo As Long
    FileName As String
    ErrorType As String
    ErrorCell As String
    ErrorCellValue As Variant
End Type
```

And then in your routine, call it like this:

```
Dim errorArray(0) As ErrRecord
With errorArray(0)
    .SerialNo = 12345
    .FileName = "Test.xls"
    .ErrorType = "Bad error"
    .ErrorCell = "1234"
    .ErrorCellValue = "Test"
End With
```

Comment: What if I want a dynamic array. Like I am storing data retrieved from DB, so columns may differ in datatype.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.  Neat and clean solution.