# VBA user-defined-datatype array to range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pass-by-reference

I have a public variant array populated with a range containing several data types (dates, numbers, strings, booleans...)

I have functions taking those types as parameter and works on the "columns" of my array.
Each function have been tested by passing them directly variable (not arrays) and worked fine.

But when the program tries to compile, it returns me an error : "argument Type Byref not compatible". To me, I don't declare things how i should. Any advice would be welcome.

```
Dim myArray() As Variant

myArray = importedRange.Value
myArray (12) = aFunction(myArray (3))
```

Edit :

I the public variant array is no more. I replaced it with an array of a new private type composed of the types I needed. It works perfectly.

In order to fill this array I copy data from ranges using "For" loops (for a test purpose but i'm open to any upgrade).

I wonder now if there is a way to copy my new array in a given range avoiding using more loops.
This line worked for my first variant array but doesent with the new one.

```
Dim zoneStockage As Range
Set zoneStockage = Sheets("Archive_Test").Range("A1")
Dim tableauFactures(3) As Facture

'allocating my new array.
```

(I've skipped this code because there are 18 parameters composing it.)

```
zoneStockage.Resize(UBound(tableauFactures, 1), 18).Value = tableauFactures
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have an array of Variant type so everything in it is a variant. If your functions *require* typed arguments, either change them to pass ByVal, or use a conversion function (eg `CDbl()`) when passing the values.

Comment: I'm afraid converting data, send and returned to functions would not be optimizated at all. Same for byVal...
Is there a way to type only certain "columns" of my array ?
The best for me would that my functions took thoses array "columns".
The main reason why i work with arrays is to have an optimized code.

Comment: Would it be possible (and a good way) to declare an array of arrays (with sub arrays typed differently) ?

Comment: If you type the arrays, you will not be able to load them in one pass from the range.

Comment: An array can be of only one type - you can't (eg) have one "column" of a 2D array as (eg) Double.  You will need to make some adjustments to how you process the data if your current setup is giving you problems.  I would not worry about efficiency until you get it actually working. Then *if it seems slow* you can try to optimize it.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.
Using the excel sheets as a replacement for the array may work but I've read it was not a good way to code. (I'm a junior programmer so I want to learn the best possible way to do things in order to avoid bad habits later)

Comment: I'm trying using an array of private type composed of the sub-types I need but have no success populating it from the range.
there is an exemple of private type : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069082/vba-how-to-declare-an-array-with-elements-with-different-datatype

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, maybe not more effective than using "sheets.range" but it works anyway:

```
For i = 0 To 5
    With myUDT(i)
        .Name = Sheets("a").Range("A" & i)
        .Color = Sheets("a").Range("B" & i)
        .dateCreation = Sheets("a").Range("C" & i)
        .dateDebutContrat = Sheets("a").Range("D" & i)
    End With
Next i
```